# How to import xml file as a resource into library project in spring boot 2.1.7 RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my project hierarchy have a parent and a library project.
Library project have a DataSourceConfiguration like this

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:conf/spring/datasource-config.xml")
public class DataSourceConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context = null;

    /**
     * Method to create DataAccessorDelegate bean
     * 
     * @return DataAccessorDelegate
     */
    @Bean(name = BeanNames.DATA_ACCESSOR_DELEGATE)
    @Scope("singleton")
    public DataAccessorDelegate getdataAccessorDelegate()
    {
        DataAccessorDelegate dataAccessorDelegate = new DataAccessorDelegate();
        return dataAccessorDelegate;
    }
```

My parent class and updated DataSourceConfiguration are given below

```
public class XERServiceMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(XERServiceMain.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:"classpath:conf/spring/datasource-config.xml","classpath*:**/module-context.xml")
                .build().run(args);
  }
}
```

DataSourceConfiguration

```
@Configuration
    public class DataSourceConfiguration
    {
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context = null;

        /**
         * Method to create DataAccessorDelegate bean
         * 
         * @return DataAccessorDelegate
         */
        @Bean(name = BeanNames.DATA_ACCESSOR_DELEGATE)
        @Scope("singleton")
        public DataAccessorDelegate getdataAccessorDelegate()
        {
            DataAccessorDelegate dataAccessorDelegate = new DataAccessorDelegate();
            return dataAccessorDelegate;
        }
```

Is it possible to import resources xml file into library project like this?